# Wireless Xbox one controller on Win10 turning off

Tags: controllers, windows-10

I have had this controller for over 2 months now, I mainly used it to play on the Xbox, but when I attached it to the PC 1 month ago It keeps disconnecting automatically from the first day I connected it wirelessly on the PC, I do not have a wire to plug into the PC so I use the wireless adapter I bought.

I've been playing Dark Souls ever since I used this controller on the PC, This is not a battery issue, as I have bought 12 AA batteries and tried them all on the controller, sometimes the controller won't turn off and I'd play the entire day normally, but most of the time it would turn on for about 5-30 seconds and then turn off on its own. I made sure the batteries were fine and I also bought another patch in the local store around my house, but the controller still turns off randomly.

I have downloaded a recommended app for the game to run it smoothly and better on PC, but the controller still has problems. I thought the problem may be because of the adapter itself, but I used my brother's adapter and it's having the same problem. I have also tried to update the firmware for the controller, but there are no updates.

One thing I did notice was that all the batteries I bought, and I have tested different combinations with different batteries, is that the battery in the Accessories app would always say Critical for some reason.

EDIT:

- watch vid, also, my controller turned off after I finished recording